# Getting empty events in response of receipt. I am using Infura+web3.js+ropsten

Tags: web3js, events, ropsten

JS code

```
contract.methods
  .myFunction(
    "data1",
    1568545262,
    1568631662,
    1568718062,
    "0xD4496dA2a4b376fC8s4d786EB6B71483436077c4"
  )
  .send({
    from: "0xD4496dA2a4b376fC8s4d786EB6B71483436077c4",
    gas: "3000000",
    value: web3.utils.toWei("0.01", "ether")
  })
  .on("transactionHash", function(hash) {
    //console.log(hash);
  })
  .on("confirmation", function(confirmationNumber, receipt) {
    //console.log(confirmationNumber, receipt);
  })
  .on("receipt", function(receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
    //console.log("blocknumber:", receipt.blockNumber);
    //console.log("Event: ", receipt.events);
  })
  .on("error", console.error);
```

Smart Contract code:

```
 event eventA(
    uint data,
    uint n1,
    uint n2,
    uint n3,
    address Addr1
);

function myFunction(

    // function Code 
    emit eventA(
        data1,num1,num2,num3,addr
    );
}
```

output:

**{ blockHash: '0x83850fbb72e6376e8455b57e6bec75f043f9b90b1c0a02d4bf159052f77e6073',
  blockNumber: 6377715,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 2713822,
  from: '0xd4496da2a4b376fc8ce4786eb6b71483436077c4',
  gasUsed: 24984,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  status: true,
  to: '0xb5fe528b887a52ded9196585ec698a66b366264d',
  transactionHash: '0xbdc6816b32572d1bfe28ddf7ad6f0d5282c025fff1fe78ca88b01e24360dd876',
  transactionIndex: 56,
  events: {} }**

How can I catch that event?

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the right contract (i.e., byte-code) deployed?

Comment: Yes. If I deploy same contract in Remix, I can see event in the logs. Same contract I used for web3 but getting empt response. I'll check again.

Comment: My bytecode was wrong. I need help with bytecode conversion. According to latest solc docs, we need to get evm.bytecode.object and then convert it into hexformat. Right?